# Wix 3.11 installation error with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have installed the wix 3.11 as shown
[image]

I am creating custom actions project and when i compile it, i get the following error:
[image]

Visual Studio extension as this:
[image]

My proj config is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" InitialTargets="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">   <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{87D73A22-1F8C-4A97-88A9-AED1B641FF7A}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>CustomAction2</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>CustomAction2</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>   </PropertyGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>   </ItemGroup>   <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="CustomAction.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Content Include="CustomAction.config" />   </ItemGroup>   <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />   <Import Project="$(WixCATargetsPath)" Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' != '' " />   <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets" Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsPath)' == '' AND Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\WiX\v3.x\Wix.CA.targets') " />   <Target Name="EnsureWixToolsetInstalled" Condition=" '$(WixCATargetsImported)' != 'true' ">
    <Error Text="The WiX Toolset v3.11 (or newer) build tools must be installed to build this project. To download the WiX Toolset, see http://wixtoolset.org/releases/" />   </Target> </Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you also install the visual studio extension?  Do that first and create a brand new custom action project and see if the problem reproduces.  If it does, compare the two .CSPROJ files.

Comment: added screenshot for same